# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by

Tags: mysql

i am getting this error when i started my xampp application.

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

in order to resolve it i tried to restart my xampp application but it didn't work  searched for solution on google and found out in which they said i should delete mysql files and etc and that didn't work as well help me please. thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we cannot because there is not enough information. Using mysql and operating system error logs you need to determine the roo cause of the issue.

Comment: the issue was that mysql service was already running in background i thiink so they asked me to remove it and it started working.

Answer (score 9):

- At first, go to **Xampp\mysql** then rename the **data** folder as you want.
- Copy the **backup** folder and rename it as **data**.
- then copy all the database folders from the old data_folder and paste in new data folder

> Don't delete any file

Run your xampp. Your xampp will be ok now.

Comment: Worked for me. But here you missed one thing, it also require to copy ibdata1 and ib_logfileXX files from old data folder to new data.
It will work perfect!